# Adding a new List to a SharePoint 2007 Site Using C# Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2007

I'm working with a Sharepoint site, I'm accessing this site using Web Services,

```
var client = new SiteWebReference.Lists();
        System.Net.NetworkCredential passCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        client.Credentials = passCredentials;
```

This allows me to pull out lists from the site, I'm now trying to also add a new list to the SharePoint site but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

The generated `Lists` object has an `AddList` method.  Call it to add a list.

Comment: How would I be able to use this, if possible can you supply and example

Comment: @SandroPerez You call `AddList`.  That's it.  What else is there to see?

Comment: I understand that part but it can't really be that simple, I'm in need of some supplement to help my doubtful mind.

Comment: @SandroPerez It can, and is, in fact that simple.  Clearly you haven't even *attempted* to solve the problem.  If you had, you'd have seen for yourself just how easy it is.